# SwiftUI navigation link and @State have problem in "onAppear()"

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a view stack ,such as root -> subViewA -> subViewB,and I pass a @State var to each other view ,this var is control something show or hide,this is my code:

```
struct RootView: View {
    
    @State var show: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .bottom)) {
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SubViewA(show: $show),
                    label: {
                        Text("to Sub View A")
                            .onAppear {
                                show = true
                                print("Conntent View appear")
                            }
                    })
            }
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .frame(width: 400, height: 70)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .offset(y: show ? 0 : 500)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct SubViewA: View {
    
    @Binding var show: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: SubViewB(show: $show),
            label: {
                Text("to Sub View B")
                    .onAppear {
                        show = true
                        print("sub View A appear")
                    }
            })
    }
}
```

```
struct SubViewB: View {
    
    @Binding var show: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Sub View B")
            .onAppear {
                show = false
                print("Sub View B appear")
            }
    }
}
```

the console output is :

```
Conntent View appear
sub View A appear
2021-08-02 15:22:58.284604+0800 NavigationLink[32349:489749] [Assert] displayModeButtonItem is internally managed and not exposed for DoubleColumn style. Returning an empty, disconnected UIBarButtonItem to fulfill the non-null contract.
Sub View B appear
Conntent View appear
```

when navigate to the subViewB,the output is "Sub View B appear" and "Content View appear",why it print the rootView's onappear() info?how can I fixed it?

Comment: works as expected without any problems for me on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 15 and macCatalyst. It maybe different on older systems.

Comment: thanks for reply. my macOS 11.4, Xcode 12.5.1, target iOS 14. that could be a system bug?

Comment: Binding is a two way connection State is a source of truth. You only have one source of truth that is triggering all the Navigation Links.

Comment: @loremipsum,i can't understand what you mean,can u tell me more?thank you!

Comment: Your state presents and hides all the links

Comment: the 'show' state only control the 'RoundedRectangle' show or hide,i only pass it to each view . the RoundedRectangle is custom tabbar, it shows in each view, I want to show it in SubViewA and hide in SubViewB

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue.... It seems like occur under iOS 15.0 device.
My device version is iOS 14.4. but iOS 15.2 Simulator works well.

rootView's onAppear is called when second hierachy child is pushing, also when poping all Views rootView's onAppear is not called.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30632043)